# Easy way to view matplotlib [plots with global color manipulation to simulate different color vision deficiencies and b&w printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, color-blindness

When producing plots with matplotlib one often has to consider different factors regarding color, when aiming for maximum accessibility.
How does the plot look when printed in black and white?
How do people with different kinds of color blindness perceive the plot?

Is there a way to globally manipulate the colors to black and white, and maybe even something to similar to this: https://www.color-blindness.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/ for previewing plots. 
I know certain colorblind-friendly palettes and cycles exist, but sometimes I want to choose colors myself and still be able to make my plots well accessible.

I imagine if there is any way to globally manimpulate colors something like this should be possible.

Comment: if you works with images then maybe use modules which works with images (instead of `matplotlib`). ie. [PIL / pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [opencv](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python) (Computer Vision).

Comment: No, I am not loading images from somewhere. I am producing plots of various types during research using matplotlib and wondered if there is an easy way for me to check if they are black and white printing and colorblindness friendly. It would be a shame if good research does not reach part of its audience because they have no color printer or have certain color vision deficiencies.

Comment: The tool you link to seems like a good way to test your plots.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest that's certainly true, but it's kind of cumbersome to save the plots in a format supported by this tool and upload them, every time something is changed. I was wondering if there was a way to automate this. Like an optional argument for the show/savefig function like colormode="bw","Red-Weak"...

Comment: There is nothing like that within matplotlib. A quick search brought up [this](https://github.com/joergdietrich/daltonize), which may be helpful?

Comment: This looks very promising. The black and white output I can probably automize somehow. An internal matplotlib solution would have been cool, but I guess that's probably as good as it gets.